# Get single string char from a string

Tags: c++

```
for each (std::string s in m_intro.text) // std::vector<string>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
            char* chr = &s.at(i);
            chr[i+1] = NULL;
            std::string t(chr);

            // other code is used below not shown as not relivent

        }

    }
```

I want to get a char from a string. Each char I get I then want to turn into a string (there is a function that needs a `const std::string&`)

The above code works once, but after the first loop the entire of `s` is null. I can see why this is happening.

What I want is to get the next char from `s` on each loop and store it as a string.

Comment: what are you attempting to accomplish?

Comment: this is one way c++ lets you shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: This doesn't look like C++ to me.

Comment: @DanielA.White -- "What I want is to get the next char from s on each loop and store it as a string."

Comment: @PoiXen: He means, what is your wider goal? What problem are you trying to solve? Not _how_ are you trying to solve it.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal -- "there is a function that needs a const std::string&" -- I only want to pass one char at a time from a string, not the whole thing.

Comment: @PoiXen: Yes, I know that. It seems you're not understanding the follow-up questions. _Why_ is there a function that needs a character at a time? What is it? What is your string?

Comment: you can use `str[x]` to access each character of a string. you could write: ` std::string` `char` `=` `str[x];` `new_string` `+=` `char;` `//new_stringdefined outside for loop`

Comment: @DanielA.White: This is one way **C** lets you shoot yourself in the foot. The code that is the problem is not C++ (it is messing with pointers). All the C++ code is well behaved.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
char* chr = &s.at(i);
chr[i+1] = NULL;
std::string t(chr);
```

When the `char` was part of a C-string (or `char` array), you used the right (if antiquated) approach of setting the next element to `NULL` to terminate the string.

However in this case, this is not relevant; you're just indexing into a `std::string` and replacing all its characters with `NULL`, which is of course not what you meant.

`std::string` has a constructor you can use to avoid this nastiness:

```
std::string t(1, s.at(i));
//   ^        ^    ^
//   |        |    |
// string     |    |
//            |    |
//     of length 1 |
//        char     |
//                 |
//     each having value s.at(i)
```

No need to mess with pointers or `char` arrays or `NULL`-termination.

Comment: **Note:** Francois's approach with `.substring` is good, too.

Answer (score 2):

You clear out the string yourself by assigning `'\0'` to its elements in a loop. You should not be using internals of the string. Instead, create a temporary one-character string, and re-assign its first character in a loop, like this:

```
for each (std::string s in m_intro.text) // std::vector<string>
    {
        string tmp("_");
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
            tmp[0] = s[i];

            // other code is used below not shown as not relivent

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this for homework? Why do you think "after the first loop the entire of `s` is null"? It seems pretty clear to me looking at the code, and it denotes a lack of understanding how strings work in C/C++ on your part...

This being said, here is a possible way to achieve what you are looking for:

```
for each (std::string s in m_intro.text) // std::vector<string>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
            std::string t = s.substring(i, 1);

            // other code is used below not shown as not relevant
        }

    }
```

Comment: He's understood the problem very well. Alas I can't downvote you because your solution is good :)

Answer (score 0):

```
char* chr = &s.at(i);
```

Here is a mistake. You edit source string, making second its element \0 (zero-terminated), truncating it.
Try this code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
            char chrstr[2];
            chrstr[0] = s.at(i);
            chrstr[1] = NULL;
            std::string t(chrstr);

            // other code is used below not shown as not relivent
        }
```